# How to prevent this deadlock with an INSERT and UPDATE statements inside a transaction

Tags: mysql, transactions, innodb

I have two tables `table_a` and `table_b`. In my application, I have a business method which does the following:

```
// it is one transaction

INSERT INTO table_b (join_col) VALUES (some_value);

UPDATE table_a a 
JOIN table_b b ON a.join_col = b.join_col AND a.column_a = b.column_b
SET a.column_c = a.column_c + 1;
```

I'm using InnoDB engine and the problem is, when I run my method in parallel or almost in parallel, I often get this error message:

> Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction

It seems, like the first transaction started to update `table_a` and put a lock on `table_b`, while the second parallel transaction can not insert into `table_b`, because it is locked.

If I comment my `UPDATE` statement, it starts working. Both transactions insert into `table_b` without problems. So, how can I fix it? If it matters, I'm using MySQL 5.7.

Comment: How frequent is the deadlock, as a percentage of the time?

Comment: Every second time I get this deadlock. 50%.

Comment: Do you really have no WHERE clause in your UPDATE statement?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're locking table b, then table a. Probably the a lock is an index lock.

Try this, to always grab an appropriate lock on table a first.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
  SELECT COUNT(join_col) INTO @counter 
    FROM table_a a
   WHERE a.join_col = some_value
     FOR UPDATE;
  INSERT INTO table_b (join_col) VALUES (some_value);
  UPDATE table_a a 
    JOIN table_b b ON a.join_col = b.join_col 
                  AND a.column_a = b.column_b
     SET a.column_c = a.column_c + 1;
COMMIT;
```

The `INTO @counter` stuff prevents the first SELECT from returning a result set to your program.

If that doesn't work, try using [LOCK TABLES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/lock-tables.html). It's a big hammer, but effective.

```
LOCK TABLES table_a, table_b WRITE;
 your queries
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Comment: So, if I use this trick, my second transaction will wait untill the first transaction commits?

Comment: Yes, the idea is to always take the lock on table_a at the beginning of the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

That seems like strange code.

1. Insert a bunch of values into B.
2. Use *all* those values to update another table.

Well, If you are playing with the *same* B in another thread, what do you expect?  You don't want the list of things in B to be changing.

Consider using a `TEMPORARY TABLE` for B??